# Merging overlapping coordinates to polygons

Tags: qgis, merge

Currently I have circa 6,700 geocoded sports club data which indicates the location of the club, the grant they received in a particular year, along with the intended sport.

My shapefile consists of 3,409 regions. What I would like to do is merge the attribute table of my shapefile which contains regional information with my geocoded sports data.

However, while I could normally use "Join Attributes by Location" the issue here is that certain clubs receive more than one grant during the time period (thus an overlapping polygon) and there is also more than one club in a region. Thus, when I use the "Join Attributes by Location" function only one piece of information is taken for each region. So rather than having 6,700 lines of data, I only have 3,409.

In essence I want all my geocoded sports information to be treated as unique.

Is there anyway to merge these two datasets so I'll have regional information for every sports club, rather than having just one piece of sports information for every region?

Comment: @Joseph - Thank you very much. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Awesome buddy! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same **Join Attributes by Location** tool but **switch** your inputs.

Make your *Target layer* the sports club data (with the 6,700 data features) and the *Join layer* the grants data (polygon).

The output should contain 6700 features, each with regional info from the sports club data.